# Only subject set in MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, email

I am trying to use the MFMailComposeViewController, I have set all the fields I want to be set as follows :

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *message = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [message setMessageBody:@"My message here"  isHTML:NO];
    [message setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"my@domain.com"]];
    [message setSubject:@"Request Info"];
    message.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    // Present mail view controller on screen
    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
    [navController presentViewController:message animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

However when the mail compose window comes up the only field which is set is the Subject and nothing else, the body, the to field are all empty. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test it on a real device with mail account set.